# How to make a Sprite have multiple armors/weapons/Accesories

Tags: 2d, game-mechanics

I am currently developing a game that involves a multitude of weapons, armors, etc. I am using UE4 currently as an engine because I found that easy to use. Currently in development I have found myself unable to figure out how to make it so my character has the ability to equip different items. Does anyone know of any way that I can get this to work?

Comment: If there is a *specific* issue you're running into with that technique (or you're using a different technique and having a specific issue), feel free to edit your question to clarify.